# Managing Login Timeout Expired errors against SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have the next VB.NET code being executed every hour. The code connects to that server and that database and execute some commands, not only on the database MyDatabase, but also on other databases in the same server.

As the user is a sysadmin, it has admin access to all databases without problem.

```vb
Dim ConnStr As String
Dim Conn As SqlConnection
Dim cM As SqlCommand
Try
    ConnStr = "Server=MyServer;Database=MyDatabase;User Id=MyUsername;Password=MyPassword;Connect Timeout=300"
    Dim Conn As New SqlConnection(ConnStr)
    cM = New SqlCommand("", Conn) 'The SQL code comes from an script file (*.sql)
    cM.CommandTimeout = 1800
    cM.Connection = Conn
    Conn.Open()
    cM.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch eX As Exception
    Dim strError As String = ex.Message
    If Not ex.InnerException Is Nothing Then strError &= " | " & ex.InnerException.Message
    strError = "Connection Timeout: " & Conn.ConnectionTimeout.ToString & " | " & _
        "Command Timeout: " & cM.CommandTimeout.ToString & " | " & _
        strError
    objLogging.LogErrorStep(JobID, JobName, CurrentStepName, strError)
Finally
    If Conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then Conn.Close()
    Conn.Dispose()
End Try
```

The issue we are experimenting is that some of the runs of this job are failing because of Login Timeout Expired errors:

```
Connection Timeout: 300 | Command Timeout: 1800 | TCP Provider: Timeout error [258]. 
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Login timeout expired".
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Unable to complete login process due to delay in prelogin response".
```

As you can see in the code, I'm saving the errors in a Logging table, and also saving there the current Connection Timeout and the current Command Timeout.

My surprise is that when I'm checking the errors in my Logging table, I can see the elapsed time between the command started time and the command failed time, and the elapsed time has been only 15 seconds, when my Connection Timeout is set to 300. Look at the next image:

[image]

As you can see, the difference between the EventStart and the EventStop is about 15 seconds. If the process fails because of a Connection Timeout, and it is set to 300, the elapsed time should be 300, isn't it?

Thanks for your help and comments.

EDIT 2019-05-31

After wait for one more day having set the Connect Timeout = 300 property in the OPEDATASOURCE connectionString, I got a new Login Timeout Expired this afternoon, also just in 15 seconds (See the image)

[image]

Comment: Based on the error your sql is attempting to run a command against a linked server, or uses openrowset or similar function, that's where timeout occurs.

Comment: Hi @Daniel N, you gave me the clue! Thanks! In fact, the script was using an OPENDATASOURCE command in one of the views. This OPENDATASOURCE was connecting to an external server, and the Connect Timeout was not set in the connection string of the OPENDATASOURCE command. Seems to me that this is the solution. I've added the Connect Timeout, I will post here if tomorrow we don't have any Timeout issue. That would mean that this has been the solution, as I'm having some timeouts every day.

Answer (score 0):

The connect timeout and CommandTimeout settings apply to the connection from the client to "MyDatabase".  Since your SQL Command connects to linked servers, those settings will not automatically be transferred and will have to be configured at the SQL Server level.  Note that this change applies immediately and is server wide (T-SQL):

```
EXEC sp_configure 'remote login timeout', 300;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE ;  
GO  

EXEC sp_configure 'remote query timeout', 1800;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE ;  
GO
```

See these two related MSDN links:

[Remote Login Timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-login-timeout-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017)

[Remote Query Timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-query-timeout-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Thanks N0Alias , I knew these two settings, but my goal was not to change all the timeouts for the entire server, just fix my specific issues. @Daniel N gave me the clue in the comment he did in my post.

Comment: Same here. CATH TRY does not CATCH this specific error (login timeout expired,  [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 50000),  [SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 7412)).